# <font color='#ff0000'> does't work in Android

Tags: android, html, textview

I use  tag in Android TextView like this,

```
mNameStr = "<font color='#ff0000'>" + "myword" + "</font>";
result = Html.fromHtml(mNameStr, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
mName.setText(result);
```

but , it does't work.Why?

Answer (score 1):

Use the most easiest way

myNameTV.setText("myword");

myNameTV.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#fd0101"));

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String mNameStr = " <font color=#ff0000> myword </font>";
mName.setText(Html.fromHtml(mNameStr), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

or try this

```
mName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#ff0000\">" + "myword " + "</font>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]Change your code as per following

```
mNameStr = "<font color=#ff0000>myword</font>";
mName.setText(Html.fromHtml(mNameStr));
```

It is working check this sample code and attached Image.

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView sampleText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);
        sampleText= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample);
        String mNameStr = "<font color=#ff0000>myword</font>";
        sampleText.setText(Html.fromHtml(mNameStr));
    }
}
```

Comment: That HTML isn't valid

Comment: I meant `color=#ff0000` isn't valid. Should be quoted

Comment: It is still does not work,I use SpannableString solved the problem.Thank you!

Comment: Check the sample code and try it.@cricket_007 `color=#ff0000` is working without quotes.